# Weird Result of String

Tags: c#, string, newline, richtextbox

just curious about it . i wonder why :

```
string str = @"//
    // Use a new char[] array of two characters (\r and \n) to break
    // lines from into separate strings. \n Use RemoveEmptyEntries
    // to make sure no empty strings get put in the string array. 
    //";
```

**result text to richTextBox was:**

```
//
    // Use a new char[] array of two characters (\r and \n) to break
    // lines from into separate strings. \n Use RemoveEmptyEntries
    // to make sure no empty strings get put in the string array. 
    //
```

but

```
string str = @"//
    // Use a new char[] array of two characters (\r and \n) to break
    // lines from into separate strings."+" \n" + @" Use RemoveEmptyEntries
    // to make sure no empty strings get put in the string array. 
    //";
```

**result text to richTextBox was:**

```
//
    // Use a new char[] array of two characters (\r and \n) to break
    // lines from into separate strings. 
 Use RemoveEmptyEntries
    // to make sure no empty strings get put in the string array. 
    //
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no literal @ before your central string " \n" 
The equivalent would be

```
string str = @"//
// Use a new char[] array of two characters (\r and \n) to break
// lines from into separate strings."+ @" \n" + @" Use RemoveEmptyEntries
// to make sure no empty strings get put in the string array. 
//";
```

\ is an escape character in normal strings, but string literals use the content exactly as is, except in the case of " which is escaped as ""

Comment: @Elegiac No it wont. It will read "\n" as a simple string, but without `@` it'll also find escape sequences in it.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no @ before the "\n" in you second example. Any escape sequence after @ (verbatim string literal) will be ignored. In your first example it was ignored but not in the second.

Have a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx